# Resources$NotFoundException when trying to play a video on Android?

Tags: android, video, resources, crash

> E/AndroidRuntime( 5751): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Android/com.example.Android.OpenByApiActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 5751):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 5751):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 5751):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 5751):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 5751): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001

Does anybody know why this is being thrown? This is my code for the video and xml

```
public class OpenByApiActivity extends Activity implements Callback {


MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.video);
StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    String[] clearLogcat = new String[] { "logcat", "-c",};
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(clearLogcat);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
              File location = new File("/sdcard/MediaTestFiles/sample.mp4");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(location);      
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(176, 144);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, path);         
    if(mp!=null){
    mp.start();
                   }}}
                @Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>

   <SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this and tell me if you still have the same problem

```
final File location = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MediaTestFiles/sample.mp4");
```

i guess the problem may be with your path.

**UPDATE**

can you move this line

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    //mp.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    mp.setDisplay(arg0);
}
```

inside the onSurfaceCreated.

Comment: wow the audio works, however the video doesn't come up? Only the audio ):. Know what's wrong?

Comment: @Master: if this works can you consider marking this as an answer.

Comment: i'm sorry but where is the the onSurfaceCreated?

Comment: @Master: it's in your question. ;). anyway i updated my response.